# Can I increment version number of iOS/Android app even users don't install app to update

Tags: android, ios

I create iOS and Android apps as hybrid app.
My apps send HTTP request to server, and then get HTML,CSS,JS etc.

Users don't need to update my apps until I change native side project.
It means that sometimes my apps version don't changes even I provide new functions or fix bugs.

It's wired for user. I should display increment version number when my apps have changes.
I want to increment version number of my apps even users don't install my apps to update.

Is there any good way to achieve it?

I come up with one idea to directly change setting file like Android manifest file.
However, I don't know whether it's good and works....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.

AndroidManifest is XML file attached to your APK and could not be changed when it's installed - only by application update (I mean installing new APK with incremented version number).

In iOS situation is the same. Version code is attached in Info.plist file which, like AndroidManifest, is just file attached to your application archive and could not be changed.

I don't think you can dynamically change your version code - because this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I gave up it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible for iOS, you need to submit new version for version number to change for your app

Also not possible for android as well

Answer (score 0):

For Android that's simply possible, for iOS, because of the Sandbox and Apples protections, not. (If not jailbroken)

You could let the app have a settings/information section where it displays current version, and this version will be loaded from your server as well as the HTML, CSS and JS.